# Error: "AndroidFixManifests" parameter is not supported, when run in Release mode

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, james

Error: The "AndroidFixManifests" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinDownloadArchives" task loaded from assembly: Xamarin.Build.Download, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null from the path:
C:\Users\GauravPatil.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.11.3\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll.
Verify that the parameter exists on the task, the `<UsingTask>` points to the correct assembly, and it is a settable public instance property
in IMS.Mobile.Droid

I am trying to run application in release mode.

Comment: Try to Open the.csproj file and delete the parameters for AndroidFixManifests. Then, save the project and build it.

Comment: Ok thanks let me check

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/1063#issuecomment-1334583186 suggests using Solution Explorer / Manage Nuget packages, to install Xamarin.Build.Download.

Answer (score 9):

As a summary, I will post an answer.

There is a known issue about this problem just as ToolmakerSteve said, you can follow up this issue: [here](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/1063).

You can try the workaround as follows:

- Right click your solution -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution-->
  On the Browse tab, search for `Xamarin.Build.Download` nuget
- install `Xamarin.Build.Download` nuget for all of the projects and ensure to install the same version (0.11.4)
- Clean and rebuild your Solution.

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. I can build the project as usual.

Comment: Hi @Jessie Zhang -MSFT. I think only the one who asked the question can do that.

Comment: Tks, you save my day