# MAUI iOS app asks for NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription permission even though it is not declared anywhere

Tags: ios, .net, permissions, maui, maui-ios

Recently we add IAP to our MAUI app. Everything seem to be fine except for iOS, when starting, a [permission dialog like this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102229) shows up. After some searching, it's `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` permission. However we do not have it anywhere in our files. I suspect it's from a package we added recently but I do not recall MAUI iOS permission can be added with attributes like Android. These are the new packages:

- `Plugin.InAppBilling` for IAP.
- `Xamarin.Build.Download`: we have to add this due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76586585/error-androidfixmanifests-parameter-is-not-supported-when-run-in-release-mod). Installing this package allows us to build the iOS app successfully even though the error message seems to be for Android.

I have used VS Code's File content search and search for `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` in all files (including in the `obj` and `bin` folders) but I cannot find it anywhere.

What's the problem here? How do I remove that permission?

**UPDATE**: It only happens to **debug** (test) build. In Release build uploaded to TestFlight, it's not there any more.